# How to create a Stacked area chart with mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've been looking for a way to create a Stacked Area chart with MPAndroidChart such as the [one available with NVD3](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html)

I successfully managed to create a Line chart and tried to add several lines and filled the area, but the values can't be stacked. I don't want to use the Stacked Bar chart because the value progression is not visually explicit enough.

Is there any easy possibilities to do that with MPAndroidChart?

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a custom FillFormatter and LineChartRenderer. See the example here.

[Android - Fill the color between two lines using MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342597/android-fill-area-between-two-lines-using-mpandroidchart/43452404#43452404)

Comment: The fill color will help to show it as an area chart but the values will be displayed with an increased value instead of the real value