# Android - Fill the color between two lines using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

[image]

I am using setFillFormatter, but it's not helping me and, **setfillColor()** crosses the second line(black) as there is no way to stop the first line(Yellow) at Y values of the second line.
I want to implement something like this:

```
dataSet.setFillFormatter(new IFillFormatter() {

            @Override
            public float getFillLinePosition(ILineDataSet dataSet, LineDataProvider dataProvider) {
                return //return Y value of the second line for current X of line being filled;
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to find the Y value of the second line for each X of first line? I see both **dataSet** and **dataProvider** returns fixed values for each call of getFillLinePosition.

Comment: I don't think you can do that using the provided methods in the library. You will probably have to write a custom renderer to do that. Look at `LineChartRenderer`

Comment: Is it possible to fill the space between two lines on a **CombinedChart**? Please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986048/mpandroidchart-how-to-fill-area-between-two-lines-on-a-combinedchart

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks David Rawson for pointing me towards `LineChartRenderer`. I am able to color the area between two lines.

We need to make two major changes.

1. Implement a custom `FillFormator` to return the dataset of another line.

   ```
   public class MyFillFormatter implements IFillFormatter {
   private ILineDataSet boundaryDataSet;

   public MyFillFormatter() {
       this(null);
   }
   //Pass the dataset of other line in the Constructor 
   public MyFillFormatter(ILineDataSet boundaryDataSet) {
       this.boundaryDataSet = boundaryDataSet;
   }

   @Override
   public float getFillLinePosition(ILineDataSet dataSet, LineDataProvider dataProvider) {
       return 0;
   }

   //Define a new method which is used in the LineChartRenderer
   public List<Entry> getFillLineBoundary() {
       if(boundaryDataSet != null) {
           return ((LineDataSet) boundaryDataSet).getValues();
       }
       return null;
   }}
   ```
2. Implement a custom `LineChartRenderer` to draw and fill the enclosed path.

   ```
   public class MyLineLegendRenderer extends LineChartRenderer {

   public MyLineLegendRenderer(LineDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
       super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
   }

   //This method is same as it's parent implemntation
   @Override
   protected void drawLinearFill(Canvas c, ILineDataSet dataSet, Transformer trans, XBounds bounds) {
       final Path filled = mGenerateFilledPathBuffer;

       final int startingIndex = bounds.min;
       final int endingIndex = bounds.range + bounds.min;
       final int indexInterval = 128;

       int currentStartIndex = 0;
       int currentEndIndex = indexInterval;
       int iterations = 0;

       // Doing this iteratively in order to avoid OutOfMemory errors that can happen on large bounds sets.
       do {
           currentStartIndex = startingIndex + (iterations * indexInterval);
           currentEndIndex = currentStartIndex + indexInterval;
           currentEndIndex = currentEndIndex > endingIndex ? endingIndex : currentEndIndex;

           if (currentStartIndex <= currentEndIndex) {
               generateFilledPath(dataSet, currentStartIndex, currentEndIndex, filled);

               trans.pathValueToPixel(filled);

               final Drawable drawable = dataSet.getFillDrawable();
               if (drawable != null) {

                   drawFilledPath(c, filled, drawable);
               } else {

                   drawFilledPath(c, filled, dataSet.getFillColor(), dataSet.getFillAlpha());
               }
           }

           iterations++;

       } while (currentStartIndex <= currentEndIndex);
   }

   //This is where we define the area to be filled.
   private void generateFilledPath(final ILineDataSet dataSet, final int startIndex, final int endIndex, final Path outputPath) {

       //Call the custom method to retrieve the dataset for other line
       final List<Entry> boundaryEntry = ((MyFillFormatter)dataSet.getFillFormatter()).getFillLineBoundary();

       final float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();    
       final Path filled = outputPath;
       filled.reset();

       final Entry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(startIndex);

       filled.moveTo(entry.getX(), boundaryEntry.get(0).getY());
       filled.lineTo(entry.getX(), entry.getY() * phaseY);

       // create a new path
       Entry currentEntry = null;
       Entry previousEntry = null;
       for (int x = startIndex + 1; x <= endIndex; x++) {

           currentEntry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(x);
           filled.lineTo(currentEntry.getX(), currentEntry.getY() * phaseY);

       }

       // close up
       if (currentEntry != null && previousEntry!= null) {
           filled.lineTo(currentEntry.getX(), previousEntry.getY());
       }

       //Draw the path towards the other line 
       for (int x = endIndex ; x > startIndex; x--) {
           previousEntry = boundaryEntry.get(x);
           filled.lineTo(previousEntry.getX(), previousEntry.getY() * phaseY);
       }

       filled.close();
   }}
   ```
3. At the end of the activity

   Set the `MyFillFormatter` to one of the `LineDataSet` passing another `LineDataSet` as argument.

   ```
   lineDataSet2.setFillFormatter(new MyFillFormatter(LineDataSet1));

   mChart.setRenderer(new MyLineLegendRenderer(mChart, mChart.getAnimator(), mChart.getViewPortHandler()));
   ```

[image]

Comment: Could you expand your answer to override `drawCubicFill()` as that method is being called rather than `drawLinearFill()`. (This is because I am calling `dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER)`.)

Comment: I have worked it out now. Please see my answer for extended version of `MyLineLegendRenderer` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118570/1617737

Comment: as it is written, if you have other lines on the chart, you are getting ClassCastException - DefaultFillFormatter cannot be cast to MyFillFormatter, so I could suggest you to add some checks in the renderer and if the FillFormatter is instanceOf DefaultFillFormatter  to use the super methods instead the ones from the MyFillFormatter

Comment: great work! do you know how to customize fill color based on LineDataSet conditions? eg. I want to have blue color if my line is above the getFillLineBoundary() and green color is my line is under that line

Comment: @Manuela  yes ..you just need to set these two attributes while creating the lineDataSet: -LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(projectionEntries, "label"); lineDataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color1)); lineDataSet.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color2));

Comment: Thanks @Amit, but it is not working for me. My issue is the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362592/android-fill-different-colors-between-two-lines-using-mpandroidchart, I just created a new question to attach the screenshot and to be clearer :)

Comment: @Amit, can this be used on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089807/how-to-change-line-and-fill-color-of-mpandroidchart-line-chart-based-on-if-y-axi

Answer (score 8):

I have used Amit's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452404/1617737), but have modified his `MyLineLegendRenderer` so that you can also fill between two **horizontal bezier** lines - e.g., if you are using `myDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER);`

I've also cleaned up the code a little bit - e.g, added comments, removed redundant code, etc.

So here is my replacement for Amit's `MyLineLegendRenderer` class:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.ChartAnimator;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.dataprovider.LineDataProvider;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;
import java.util.List;

public class MyLineLegendRenderer extends LineChartRenderer {

    MyLineLegendRenderer(LineDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    // This method is same as its parent implementation. (Required so our version of generateFilledPath() is called.)
    @Override
    protected void drawLinearFill(Canvas c, ILineDataSet dataSet, Transformer trans, XBounds bounds) {

        final Path filled = mGenerateFilledPathBuffer;

        final int startingIndex = bounds.min;
        final int endingIndex = bounds.range + bounds.min;
        final int indexInterval = 128;

        int currentStartIndex;
        int currentEndIndex;
        int iterations = 0;

        // Doing this iteratively in order to avoid OutOfMemory errors that can happen on large bounds sets.
        do {
            currentStartIndex = startingIndex + (iterations * indexInterval);

            currentEndIndex = currentStartIndex + indexInterval;
            currentEndIndex = currentEndIndex > endingIndex ? endingIndex : currentEndIndex;

            if (currentStartIndex <= currentEndIndex) {
                generateFilledPath(dataSet, currentStartIndex, currentEndIndex, filled);

                trans.pathValueToPixel(filled);

                final Drawable drawable = dataSet.getFillDrawable();
                if (drawable != null) {
                    drawFilledPath(c, filled, drawable);
                }
                else {
                    drawFilledPath(c, filled, dataSet.getFillColor(), dataSet.getFillAlpha());
                }
            }

            iterations++;

        } while (currentStartIndex <= currentEndIndex);
    }

    // This method defines the perimeter of the area to be filled for horizontal bezier data sets.
    @Override
    protected void drawCubicFill(Canvas c, ILineDataSet dataSet, Path spline, Transformer trans, XBounds bounds) {

        final float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        //Call the custom method to retrieve the dataset for other line
        final List<Entry> boundaryEntries = ((MyFillFormatter)dataSet.getFillFormatter()).getFillLineBoundary();

        // We are currently at top-last point, so draw down to the last boundary point
        Entry boundaryEntry = boundaryEntries.get(bounds.min + bounds.range);
        spline.lineTo(boundaryEntry.getX(), boundaryEntry.getY() * phaseY);

        // Draw a cubic line going back through all the previous boundary points
        Entry prev = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(bounds.min + bounds.range);
        Entry cur = prev;
        for (int x = bounds.min + bounds.range; x >= bounds.min; x--) {

            prev = cur;
            cur = boundaryEntries.get(x);

            final float cpx = (prev.getX()) + (cur.getX() - prev.getX()) / 2.0f;

            spline.cubicTo(
                    cpx, prev.getY() * phaseY,
                    cpx, cur.getY() * phaseY,
                    cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);
        }

        // Join up the perimeter
        spline.close();

        trans.pathValueToPixel(spline);

        final Drawable drawable = dataSet.getFillDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawFilledPath(c, spline, drawable);
        }
        else {
            drawFilledPath(c, spline, dataSet.getFillColor(), dataSet.getFillAlpha());
        }

    }

    // This method defines the perimeter of the area to be filled for straight-line (default) data sets.
    private void generateFilledPath(final ILineDataSet dataSet, final int startIndex, final int endIndex, final Path outputPath) {

        final float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();
        final Path filled = outputPath; // Not sure if this is required, but this is done in the original code so preserving the same technique here.
        filled.reset();

        //Call the custom method to retrieve the dataset for other line
        final List<Entry> boundaryEntries = ((MyFillFormatter)dataSet.getFillFormatter()).getFillLineBoundary();

        final Entry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(startIndex);
        final Entry boundaryEntry = boundaryEntries.get(startIndex);

        // Move down to boundary of first entry
        filled.moveTo(entry.getX(), boundaryEntry.getY() * phaseY);

        // Draw line up to value of first entry
        filled.lineTo(entry.getX(), entry.getY() * phaseY);

        // Draw line across to the values of the next entries
        Entry currentEntry;
        for (int x = startIndex + 1; x <= endIndex; x++) {
            currentEntry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(x);
            filled.lineTo(currentEntry.getX(), currentEntry.getY() * phaseY);
        }

        // Draw down to the boundary value of the last entry, then back to the first boundary value
        Entry boundaryEntry1;
        for (int x = endIndex; x > startIndex; x--) {
            boundaryEntry1 = boundaryEntries.get(x);
            filled.lineTo(boundaryEntry1.getX(), boundaryEntry1.getY() * phaseY);
        }

        // Join up the perimeter
        filled.close();

    }

}
```

You should use this class along with the other code in [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452404/1617737).