# MpAndroidChart - How to fill area between two lines on a CombinedChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452404) to a similar question shows how to fill the area between two lines on an MpAndroidChart *LineChart*.

However, rather than using LineChart, I am using **CombinedChart** (as I also have bar data to show). But applying the above solution to a CombinedChart results in this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.MyLineLegendRenderer cannot
>   be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.CombinedChartRenderer
>           at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart.setData(CombinedChart.java:96)

So I have looked at [CombinedChartRenderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/CombinedChartRenderer.java) but (unlike [LineChartRenderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java)), it does not seem to contain any functionality for filling.

So how can I fill the space between two lines on a CombinedChart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `createRenderers()` method in the `CombinedChartRenderer` class. This way you can use your own renderer for each and every type of graph that you use in the your `CombinedChart` .

It will be something like this :

```
public class MyCombinedChartRenderer extends CombinedChartRenderer {

    public MyCombinedChartRenderer(CombinedChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void createRenderers() {
        this.mRenderers.clear();
        CombinedChart chart = (CombinedChart)this.mChart.get();
        if (chart != null) {
            CombinedChart.DrawOrder[] orders = chart.getDrawOrder();
            CombinedChart.DrawOrder[] var3 = orders;
            int var4 = orders.length;

            for(int var5 = 0; var5 < var4; ++var5) {
                CombinedChart.DrawOrder order = var3[var5];
                switch(order) {
                    case BAR:
                        if (chart.getBarData() != null) {
                            this.mRenderers.add(new BarChartRenderer(chart, this.mAnimator, this.mViewPortHandler));
                        }
                        break;
                    case BUBBLE:
                        if (chart.getBubbleData() != null) {
                            this.mRenderers.add(new BubbleChartRenderer(chart, this.mAnimator, this.mViewPortHandler));
                        }
                        break;
                    case LINE:
                        if (chart.getLineData() != null) {
                            // replace with you own Line chart renderer
                            //this.mRenderers.add(new LineChartRenderer(chart, this.mAnimator, this.mViewPortHandler));
                            this.mRenderers.add(new MyLineChartRenderer(chart, this.mAnimator, this.mViewPortHandler));
                        }
                        break;
                    case CANDLE:
                        if (chart.getCandleData() != null) {
                            this.mRenderers.add(new CandleStickChartRenderer(chart, this.mAnimator, this.mViewPortHandler));
                        }
                        break;
                    case SCATTER:
                        if (chart.getScatterData() != null) {
                            this.mRenderers.add(new ScatterChartRenderer(chart, this.mAnimator, this.mViewPortHandler));
                        }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, in the `switch` block when `case LINE:` is encountered, we replace the default renderer with our own version : `MyLineChartRenderer`.

Then finally in your Activity code, you can use this renderer with your CombinedChart :

```
CombinedChart combinedChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.barChart);
combinedChart.setRenderer(new MyCombinedChartRenderer(combinedChart, combinedChart.getAnimator(), combinedChart.getViewPortHandler()));
```

Comment: Finally, to fill the area between two (horizontal bezier) lines, please see my answer to this other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118570/1617737