# MPAndroidChart : How to have colors filled between LimitLines in LineChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am trying to fill color between limit lines and have legend just like below -
[image: required screenshot]
I tried using example given here - https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/485
But unable to achieve. Last I can do about legends is to have my own textviews. But color in between is still an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a chart like that by creating a `LineDataSet` for each section and setting a fill color and a [fill formatter](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/fillformatter/) with a lower y value.

To get this chart:

[image: demo chart]
You would use

```kotlin
val ds1 = LineDataSet(listOf(Entry(0f,1f), Entry(10f,1f)), "Low").apply {
    setDrawFilled(true)
    fillAlpha = 128
    fillColor = Color.YELLOW
    color = Color.YELLOW
    fillFormatter = IFillFormatter { _, _ -> 0f } // fill down to y = 0
    setDrawCircles(false)
    lineWidth = 0f
    setDrawValues(false)
    disableDashedHighlightLine()
    isHighlightEnabled = false
}

val ds2 = LineDataSet(listOf(Entry(0f,3f), Entry(10f,3f)), "Mid").apply {
    setDrawFilled(true)
    fillAlpha = 128
    fillColor = Color.GREEN
    color = Color.GREEN
    fillFormatter = IFillFormatter { _, _ -> 1f } // fill down to y = 1
    setDrawCircles(false)
    lineWidth = 0f
    setDrawValues(false)
    disableDashedHighlightLine()
    isHighlightEnabled = false
}

val ds3 = LineDataSet(listOf(Entry(0f,7f), Entry(10f,7f)), "High").apply {
    setDrawFilled(true)
    fillAlpha = 128
    fillColor = Color.RED
    color = Color.RED
    fillFormatter = IFillFormatter { _, _ -> 3f } // fill down to y = 3
    setDrawCircles(false)
    lineWidth = 0f
    setDrawValues(false)
    disableDashedHighlightLine()
    isHighlightEnabled = false
}

val dsLine = LineDataSet(listOf(Entry(1f,2f), Entry(4f,5f), Entry(6f,4f)), "Points").apply {
    color = Color.BLACK
    setCircleColor(Color.BLACK)
    lineWidth = 2f
    setDrawValues(false)
    circleHoleColor = Color.BLACK
    circleRadius = 3f
}

chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
chart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 6f
chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false

chart.data = LineData(listOf(ds1, ds2, ds3, dsLine))
chart.description.text = ""
```

Note that this solution only works for filling to horizontal lines. If you want to fill to non-horizontal lines you will need a more complicated solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342597/android-fill-the-color-between-two-lines-using-mpandroidchart/43452404#43452404)